# GRE and IPSec Tunnel on the same interface

Tags: cisco, ipsec, tunneling

i have one route cisco 2800 series with a GRE+IPSec vpn tunnel configured.
I need to create a new tunnel, but now this is a IPSec tunnel. What i want to know is that is possible to configure different types of vpn tunnel using the same interface (outside).

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question. If you're asking whether you can have multiple IPSec tunnels on the same Internet facing interface, the answer is yes. If you asking if you can have PPTP, L2TP, and IPSec running simultaneously on the same Internet facing interface, the answer is yes. If you asking whether you can run a IPSec/L2TP tunnel inside of a pre-existing VPN tunnel, the answer is no.